# Understanding clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I need a help with clustering here. I need to understand grouping of variables in sets, so I did the following:

1. I got the data and made sure that it is of a float type
2. I normalized these values using x = (x - min)/(max - min), where min
   and max are the variables that indicate min and max in the data
   range
3. I used np.array function to convert it to numpy array
4. Then I am trying to use bandwidth (to use ManShift) or DBSCAN functions to perform the processing, but it traps with the `"ValueError: data type not understood"` error. What am I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code -

```
print ('Minimum value is {0}, maximum is {1}'.format(min_value, max_value))
for position in range(0, len(sub_set)):
    sub_set[position] = (sub_set[position] - min_value)/(max_value - min_value)

data = np.array(sub_set)

print (type(data))
print len(data)
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(data, quantile=0.2, n_samples=len(data))
```

Regards Matvey

Comment: @bibhas I removed the greetings corresponding to what was said [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and at least `np.array` *is* code

Answer (score 1):

For one-dimensional data, you gain little by doing clustering. Instead, use **kernel density estimation** or similar methods that exploit orderedness of your data.

Because meanshift, DBSCAN etc. are designed for multivariate data, they expect a *multidimensional* matrix, but you were giving a one-dimensional matrix instead. Use `reshape` to fix this.

In general, learn your APIs - you can use `numpy` much more effectively, by *first* converting your data into numpy, then performing all the other operations in *vectorized* form.

```
data = numpy.array(data)
data = (data - data.min()) / data.ptp() # Scale to 0:1
dens = gaussian_kde(data).evaluate(data)
```

will yield density estimates for each point in data. Try splitting your data on local minima of this density estimate.

Have a look at this curve for your data:

```
plot(gaussian_kde(data).evaluate(np.linspace(data.min(),data.max())))
```

Does splitting at local minima yield the desired result?